# Panoramio & Weather Layers zIndex Lower Than Polygon Overlay Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps, google-weather-api

Is it possible to make Panoramio Pictures and WeatherLayer icons appear above (have a higher zIndex than) a polygon?

I have a map with transparent Polygon Overlays, and when I add the Panoramio or WeatherLayers to the map, the Panoramio photos and weather icons appear below the polygon overlays.

The pictures and weather icons can be seen below the polygon because the polygon is partially transparent, but the user cannot interact with those photos or icons because the polygon is on top of them.

The screen shot below shows an example of this:

[image: Example]

You can view an example page [here](http://slimer.dyndns.info:84/map_example/map_layers_example.php).

You can add and remove the different overlays/layers. I've tried setting the zIndex of the polygon to negative numbers, but they always appear above the Panoramio and WeatherLayer icons.

The [PanoramioLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PanoramioLayer) and [PanoramioLayerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#PanoramioLayerOptions) API references don't say anything about a zIndex. The same goes for the [WeatherLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#WeatherLayer) and [WeatherLayerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#WeatherLayerOptions) API references.

Answer (score 1):

You're need to set option to the polygon:
**clickable**: false

But all polygon's mouse events won't work